# Why would SocketChannelImpl$DefaultOptionsHolder not be found?

Tags: java, classloader, nio

On one of our services, we see the following errors in stderr and communications stop after that.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no net in java.library.path

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl$DefaultOptionsHolder
```

They go away when the service is restarted, but recur after several hours! What could be causing this?

We're running Oracle's server-jre and I verified that rt.jar contains the class in the error. I have also confirmed that no changes were made to JRE, while the service was running.

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError either means the class could not be found, *or* the class was found and loaded but the static initializer failed when it was called.  Your error messages indicate the latter: the class was found, but static initialization failed.  There is typically a "Caused by" in this case with the error, and given that you included the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, I suspect this is the cause of the problem.  As for why that happened, I don't know; it looks like your JRE is corrupt if it was unable to find an internal native library.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected, but I verified manually that all .so files are in tact. Also, if I write a test program that does `System.loadLibrary("net");`, it works successfully.

Comment: Provide the full stack trace and someone might be able to guess at a deeper problem.